# refresh Jtable after inserting new row

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, jtable, derby

I have a jTable that is initialized thorough "right click> table content > bound > Import data to form " , and then the columns are shown from "right click>bind > elements". I have a insert form inside that form too and I want to refresh the jTable after inserting a new row. how should I do it?

Comment: I recommend you posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where we can test and help you a bit more, StackOverflow isn't a Code Factory.

Comment: @Frakcool I do not have any code for this part of my project! I explained it!

Comment: Then you should show us your attempt to solve this first. If you don't have an attempt to show, then it's time for you to make one. Note that a JTable will automatically refresh after you've added a new row to its model, so we will have no idea what problems you might be having if you don't show us. Voting to lock this question til you show us.

Comment: I did not know about model... I searched and found my answer... thx for your short hint ;)

Comment: Glad you've got it figured out. Note that the JTable tutorial will go over information about the model and is worth going over. The model itself is responsible for notifying the JTable (the view) that it has changed and that it should update itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DefaultTableModel model ;
  public MyJframe() {
         initComponents();
         model=new DefaultTableModel();
         jTable1.setModel(model);
         model.addColumn("DJID");
         model.addColumn("DID");
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        // Code for inserting to database
        model.addRow(new Object[]{DaneshjooID,DarsID});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```